# Image flashes and then disappears HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple code that builds the image path and then fetches it from my CDN, but whenever I open the page on a localhost server, the image flashes and then disappears. Am I doing something wrong with my CSS?

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- One G Fruit Salad Script -->
<script>
//VarLoader
var imgsource = document.getElementById("imgad");
var htmlsource = document.getElementById("htmlad");



//FuncLoader
//Pineapple is the final extension of the URL
var pineapple = "";
function getImgType (type) {
  if (type == "html") {
    pineapple = ".html";
  } else if (type == "png") {
    pineapple = ".png";
  } else if (type == "jpg") {
    pineapple = ".jpg";
  } else if (type == "jpeg") {
    pineapple = ".jpeg";
  } else if (type == "gif") {
    pineapple = ".gif";
  } else if (type == "htm") {
    pineapple = ".htm";
  } else {
    System.out.println("Error");
  };
};
//Post Ad Code
function postAd(creative, preset) {
  if (preset == ".html") {
    document.getElementById("htmlad").src = passionfruit;
  }
  else if (preset == ".htm") {
    document.getElementById("htmlad").src = passionfruit;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("imgad").src = passionfruit;
  }
};
// ### One-G FruitSalad ## //
//CodeLoader

//Mango is the URL that was passed, in raw format
var mango = window.location.search;
//Papaya is the content of the querystring. Use this in querying parameters
var papaya = new URLSearchParams(mango);
//Apple is the creativeid of the creative
var apple = papaya.get('cid');
var melon = papaya.get('type');
//Initial Creative link. Change as the CDN Endpoint changes
getImgType(melon);
var passionfruit = "https://storefrontads.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/creatives/" + apple + pineapple;
//Fruit Salad is Mixed in the body
//Make sure to include pathname for HunterTagger
</script>
<style>
body{
  height:250px;
  width:300px;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
#imgad {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}
#LogoIMG {
  padding-left: 268px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="adimg" class="AdImgClass">
    <a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">
      <img id="imgad" src=""></img>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="OneGLogo" class="LogoClass">
    <a href="https://storefront.one-g.net/servedbyoneg/" target="_blank">
      <img id="LogoIMG" src="https://storefrontads.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/one-g.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <script>
  //Mix fruit Salad
  postAd(passionfruit, pineapple);
  </script>
</body>
```

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. Looking at other posts didn't help. The source looks all right, and everything else works, it builds the link just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you open the console you can see an error that says that `System` is not defined (You can open the console with the F12 key in the browser).
To write out debug log messages in javascript you have to use `console.log` instead of `System.out.println`.

So your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- One G Fruit Salad Script -->
<script>
//VarLoader
var imgsource = document.getElementById("imgad");
var htmlsource = document.getElementById("htmlad");



//FuncLoader
//Pineapple is the final extension of the URL
var pineapple = "";
function getImgType (type) {
  if (type == "html") {
    pineapple = ".html";
  } else if (type == "png") {
    pineapple = ".png";
  } else if (type == "jpg") {
    pineapple = ".jpg";
  } else if (type == "jpeg") {
    pineapple = ".jpeg";
  } else if (type == "gif") {
    pineapple = ".gif";
  } else if (type == "htm") {
    pineapple = ".htm";
  } else {
    console.log("Error");
  };
};
//Post Ad Code
function postAd(creative, preset) {
  if (preset == ".html") {
    document.getElementById("htmlad").src = passionfruit;
  }
  else if (preset == ".htm") {
    document.getElementById("htmlad").src = passionfruit;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("imgad").src = passionfruit;
  }
};
// ### One-G FruitSalad ## //
//CodeLoader

//Mango is the URL that was passed, in raw format
var mango = window.location.search;
//Papaya is the content of the querystring. Use this in querying parameters
var papaya = new URLSearchParams(mango);
//Apple is the creativeid of the creative
var apple = papaya.get('cid');
var melon = papaya.get('type');
//Initial Creative link. Change as the CDN Endpoint changes
getImgType(melon);
var passionfruit = "https://storefrontads.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/creatives/" + apple + pineapple;
//Fruit Salad is Mixed in the body
//Make sure to include pathname for HunterTagger
</script>
<style>
body{
  height:250px;
  width:300px;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
#imgad {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}
#LogoIMG {
  padding-left: 268px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="adimg" class="AdImgClass">
    <a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">
      <img id="imgad" src=""></img>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="OneGLogo" class="LogoClass">
    <a href="https://storefront.one-g.net/servedbyoneg/" target="_blank">
      <img id="LogoIMG" src="https://storefrontads.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/one-g.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <script>
  //Mix fruit Salad
  postAd(passionfruit, pineapple);
  </script>
</body>
```

Also: disable your adBlocker! `id="adimg"` will trigger it!